# How to use Vue.js with handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, vue.js

I have some sort of conflict... variables in handlebars declarating like {{hbs_variable}}, the same as Vue.js variables {{vue_varable}}, and cause of that Vue ain't working on my website (when it's see variable from hbs, but trying to understand it by itself), how to solve that problem?

Comment: by not using handlebars and vue at the same time? Why would you need them both?

Comment: Do you simply mean the handlebars syntax IN Vue, as opposed to the handlebars.js library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. Vue.js have alternative syntaxis `\{{vue_variable}}`